# Using a Query instead of a for loop

Tags: django

Is there a way to do the following in a single line with a django query?

```
providers_with_no_contacts = []
for provider in Provider.objects.all():
    if not provider.userprofile_set.all():
        provider_with_no_contacts.append(provider)
```

Or a better way than this?

```
providers_with_no_contacts = [provider for provider in Provider.objects.all() 
                               if not provider.userprofile_set.all()]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Provider.objects.filter(userprofile__isnull=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

`providers_with_no_contacts = Provider.objects.filter(userprofile_set=None)`

Comment: That didn't work. Perhaps it is because `userprofile` is a M2M field?

Comment: Try: `.filter(userprofile__isnull=True)`. Works whether the field is a foreign key or M2M.